# Images get placed off screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

I have a script which palces images in random x, y but sometimes it gets placed of screen - how to fix that? And how to get this imgs to show under the container?

```js
function random_location(element) {
    let random_y_maximum = window.innerHeight;
    let random_x_maximum = window.innerWidth;

    let random_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (random_y_maximum - 0)) + 0;
    let random_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (random_x_maximum - 0)) + 0;

    element.style.top = random_y - get_size_y(element) + 'px';
    element.style.left = random_x - get_size_x(element) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: what does this function do  `get_size_y(element)`?

Comment: function get_size_y(element) {
    return element.offsetHeight;
}

// Gets width of element
function get_size_x(element) {
    return element.offsetWidth;
}